# Drawing with cv::circle's over a line Iterator in c++ with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator, line, draw

I'm creating an iterator line, which I pass through a `for()` and draw with `cv::circle` points. So far so good, form a line drawing, by the iterator's line points. But there is a **small drawing in the upper left corner that is not my intention**, does anyone know where I could be going wrong?

[image]

```
std::vector<cv::Point> createLineIterator(cv::Mat &frame)
{
    cv::Point p1(400, 0);
    cv::Point p2(200, 800);

    cv::LineIterator line(frame, p1, p2, 8);
    std::vector<cv::Point> points(line.count);
    for (int i = 0; i <= line.count; i++, ++line)
    {
        points.push_back(line.pos());
    }
    return points; //points that I will iterate over to create circles and draw the line
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image(500, 1000, CV_8UC1); // cria imagem

    std::vector<cv::Point> points = createLineIterator(image);
    for (auto i : points)
    {
        cv::circle(image, i, 2, cv::Scalar(255, 100, 255)); //Point-by-point drawing of the iterator line
    }

    cv::imshow("image", image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < line.count; i++, ++line)` just <, not <=

Comment: he was like this before, but thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by returning both cv::Point from the function

```
std::pair<std::pair<cv::Point, cv::Point>, std::vector<cv::Point>> createLineIterator(cv::Mat &frame){...}
```

and I called in main

```
cv::line(image, points.first.first, points.first.second, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
```

[image]

I don't know the reason for the error before when drawing with `cv::circle`, but see that the random drawing no longer exists with `cv::line`

Comment: My answer above explains why you got the artifacts. Have you read it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct version of `createLineIterator` that will eliminate the artifacts:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> createLineIterator(cv::Mat &frame)
{
    cv::Point p1(400, 0);
    cv::Point p2(200, 800);
    cv::LineIterator line(frame, p1, p2, 8);
    std::vector<cv::Point> points(line.count);
    for (int i = 0; i < line.count; i++, ++line)
    {
        points[i] = line.pos();
    }
    return points; //points that I will iterate over to create circles and draw the line
}
```

**Some explanations:**

In line 4 inside the function (same as in your code) we allocate `line.count` elements in the `std::vector`.
This is the meaning of writing `line.count` inside the `()`.

Using `push_back` in the loop (like you did) added element to the vector,
in addtion to the ones allocated in the construction line (line 4 in the function).
You end up with double the number of elements, the first half default constructed to **(0,0)**.

The **(0,0) circles** are the artifacts you observed.

Instead I assign to already allocated elements:

```
points[i] = line.pos();
```

Note - you could also use the default ctor of `std::vector`, and then add the elements with `push_back`.
But since you know the number of elements in advance it is less efficient that way.

Another important issue is the loop index being `< line.count`, instead of `<= line.count` in your code.
This is because `std::vector` indices are **0..(n-1)**, where n is the number of elements.